# Load a .csv file into a numpy array as a column vector

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I've got a .csv file that I'm trying to load into a numpy array as a column vector. When using

```
temp = np.genfromtxt(location, delimiter=',')
```

the data is a `numpy array` where the entries are represented as follows:

```
[ 0.  ...  0.  1.  0.  ... 0.], [ 0.  ...  1.  0.  0.  ... 0.]
```

whereas, I would like something like this:

```
[array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       ...
       [0],
       [0]]), array([[0], 
       [0],
       [0],
       ...
       [0],
       [1], 
       [0],
       ...)]
```

I'm able to accomplish this using

```
my_data = []

for i in range(len(temp)):
    foo = np.array([temp[i]]).T
    my_data.append(foo)
```

But am wondering if there is a more efficient way of achieving the required result.

Comment: Do you specifically want the items in the list to be arrays? Otherwise, you can do: `temp[:, :, None].tolist()`

Comment: Do you want the array to be in a list or is that a typo?

Comment: It would be better is the items in the list were arrays, that way I wouldn't need to make alterations to my main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new axis to `temp`, and cast sublists to *np arrays*:

```
temp = np.genfromtxt(location, delimiter=',')
my_data = map(np.array, temp[:, :, np.newaxis])
```

---

For Python 3, call `list` on the above result or use a list comprehension:

```
my_data = [np.array(arr) for arr in temp[:, :, np.newaxis]]
```

Comment: `list(temp[...,None])` does the same thing.